How to display columns from multiple spans in DataDog Traces view
I'm using new Traces view to find traces that contain two different type of spans.
This works and I get expected traces however in traces list I can't seem to be able to display columns from span b, only span a. Anything from b is empty.
Is this supposed to be possible somehow?
I tried creating facet on properties of b and I can filter by it but adding column through facet still does not work.
